# buddy build - There was an internal error

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, buddy-build

My build was successful using [buddybuild](http://www.buddybuild.com). Then I imported my provisioning profile, certs, etc. All of that looked good.

When I tried to validate my build with `itunesconnect` via `buddybuild`, I received this error : `There was an internal error`. Not a lot to go on here. This is all I received from `buddybuild`.

I tried validating from Xcode and it worked.

Anyone know some other steps I can take to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argh - apologies that you ran into this error! We try to make sure that you have as much context as possible to help solve the issue.

In this case, this error arises when an application is submitted to iTunes Connect using a developer provisioning profile (when, really, it requires a distribution cert). We've noted this issue and will make sure that a more helpful message is surfaced moving forward!

Generally, if you run into "There was an internal error", our team is notified and we'll reach out to you to help diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same (not quite helpful) error message. It turned out, that:

**I forgot to add the Apple ID, buddybuild is using, to iTunes Connect**.

After adding the Apple ID to iTunes Connect (with just Developer privileges) it worked like a charm.